# Why am I being logged in as someone else?

Tags: discussion, bug, security

I went to http://dev.stackexchange.com (I tried this out because I thought maybe there's a SE site for it, but it seems to redirect me to http://www.stackexchange.com) and logged in.  I pressed the button that "sends SE information to this site" and I got logged in as... Blondie21?

[image: Logged in as someone else]

Edit

It seems to login random names (girlish names) for different people, and it seems to be a SE dev site.

Comment: What if. Just what if. You shouldn't be messing with dev stuff?

Comment: @michaelb958 Is that what http://dev.stackexchange.com/ is?  Dev stuff?

Comment: Seems most likely, given that `dev.stackoverflow.com` and `dev.meta.stackoverflow.com` are already proven to exist.

Comment: Hah! That's pretty great. OpenID auth fails for me, but I didn't earnestly expect it to work anyway.

Comment: [Worked fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2IaZV.png).

Comment: No issue with StackExchange account. Got normal `account####`.

Comment: Logging in with Google account I just see my normal user name. What login steps are you taking?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm going to dev.SE and logging in, the same thing happened to my friend

Comment: Are the inbox notifications displayed yours?

Comment: @MartinSmith No, not at all

Comment: Hmmm. Ok looks like they belong to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963963/dynamic-2d-matrix-implementation. Not sure how you managed that!

Comment: I logged in with my gmail account and got logged in as pauldawg, apparently a real stack overflow user.  When I followed a link in the inbox to stack overflow, however, I arrived at the page under my correct account.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Exactly, I was very confused

Comment: Maybe for older accounts the database ids are the same for dev and live but they got out of synch at some point?

Comment: Mine's new enough that it doesn't match I think, no-repro.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy actually doesn't look age related. Andrew T has been a member for less time than Chris.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I'm saying that _newer_ users aren't affected -- I've been a member for less time than Chris.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I can confirm this isn't the case: I'm affected by this.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Yes I scotched that theory. It was just based on Aaron and I **not** being affected (both members for 5 years). But I missed the counter example of Andrew T anyway.

Comment: Hmm... could it have something to do with OpenID provider?

Comment: @hichris123 nope, two users from Google have different results.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the implementation of accounts on Stack Exchange's internal dev test network of sites, not on the public sites that non-employees should be concerned with.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Depends what the security implementations are really. Can this be used to post messages under another account or change credentials or read confidential information?

Comment: Then we should go to `dev.meta.stackoverflow.com` ;) **Edit:** It's in Portuguese! :O **Edit:** Apparently there's language option below there, but it broke anything since I couldn't login anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith A valid point. I'm pretty sure that this cannot be used to post under a different account. Internally, the site still knows who you are, and will correctly associate you with accounts accounts on specific sites, such as when you try to post. It's just the account displayed on StackExchange.com is matched against an out-of-sync database, possible leading to this effect. I also think that account credentials can't be accessed through the StackExchange.com login, but I'm not 100% sure so that's a potential information leak that needs to be checked. (edit: It looks like it's safe.)

Comment: Anyway, just want to confirm that my account there is not linked to any sites: *No associated accounts found*. And my inbox is not empty; there are 3 which were deleted. Probably true about out-of-sync DB.

Comment: There is one issue though.  I would worry about being able to mark messages in other users inboxes as read.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Presumably that would affect the dev database only, and I suspect those aren't *real* accounts at all.

Comment: Worked here too http://i.imgur.com/RQ8qodY.png

Comment: The inbox messages seemed real.  When I clicked on them they lead me to real questions on other sites opened by the person whose username was given to me.

Comment: I.e., I may have accidently marked one of pauldawg's messages as read.  As far as security issues go this is pretty minor but still it is worth mentioning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I report a serious security issue on meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/should-i-report-a-serious-security-issue-on-meta)

Comment: You should never expect dev tiers to work entirely as production sites do. ;) We're working on a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue. I'd already reported this<sup>1</sup> a couple of months ago.

In the past there was a more serious vulnerability where the same thing would happen on dev.SO. Which leaks the email address of the dummy user (actually a real user taken from the dump).

As far as I can tell, there is no PII leak here, though, the bug is pretty harmless in itself.

Though this bug can possibly be leveraged to get deeper access (that was reported too). Don't try.

<sup>1. By proxy of @Undo, because he had a private room with the devs</sup>

Comment: Obviously it is probably fixed by now, but why tell someone not to try when it could help confirm a security problem with a clear fix?

Comment: @Doorhandle If you have found a vulnerability and reported it (and know that it will be fixed), don't try and use that vulnerability to escalate, it's bad faith. Especially when the escalation has also been reported.