# How to file a report to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, reporting

How do I report an issue like a bug, error, copyright matters, hacking, etc., to the SE network?

Answer (score 6):

#### Bugs and Errors

Bug and errors for the SE network can be reported here on meta (using the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag as you did originally with this question).

---

#### Sites copying from the SE network

For issues about copies of the SE network site see [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do).

---

#### Hacking

To report problems where your account has been hacked or you suspect someone of hacking the SE network use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link which is the footer of every SE page.

---

#### Security issues

From [Reporting Security Vulnerabilities](https://stackexchange.com/about/security):

> We take security vulnerabilities very seriously and work hard to provide a secure online experience for our users. If you believe you have discovered a security issue that affects many users, please report it to us so we can investigate and correct the problem.
>
> To report a security vulnerability that affects many users, please fill out this form:
>
> [Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact)
>
> Choose "Other" as the type and include the words "Security Vulnerability". Be as detailed as you can in the steps required to reproduce the error. **Please do not post serious security issues publicly on a meta site or elsewhere**.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Has anyone ever hacked Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197383/has-anyone-ever-hacked-stack-overflow)

Comment: Clearly. Who knows what sensitive information the hackers(s) could have got. This is why hacks must be reported to SE staff ASAP

Comment: If the hack was successful then it might be a bad thing depending exactly on what was done.

Comment: @HenryWHHack You might care to read [Has anyone ever hacked Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197383/has-anyone-ever-hacked-stack-overflow)

Comment: @HenryWHHack That depends entirely on the hack. Could be a lot of people, could be virtually nobody.

Comment: @HenryWHHack 13. See the [TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) for that, as well as the DMCA copyright violation reporting process.

Answer (score 4):

For bugs, errors, and sometimes copyright matters, you can ask a question here under the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag if the question is appropriate and doesn't violate any rules of our Help Center. Copycat sites should only be reported if needed (look at this link: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) )

Most of the time, you should contact the staff via the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page. There, you can contact the staff and tell them the problems you have faced, such as thinking a person wanting to hack the site.

For security risks such as hacks, please refer to this site: https://stackexchange.com/about/security

Further reading:

- [Should I report a serious security issue on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/should-i-report-a-serious-security-issue-on-meta)
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports